# Merging/Removing a commit

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have a commit i pushed earlier today that i learned i had messed up on by not adding the correct files before pushing. I fixed the revision and re-pushed it, so now i have a revision containing literally nothing new and my real revision. This could really confuse my other team members working, so i would like to either merge both together or remove my 'blank' revision.

Here is a picture of my problem:

http://img525.imageshack.us/img525/3929/revisionproblem.png

Note that i cannot undo/rollback, it tells me the transaction is not available.

Answer (score 2):

If you've **pushed** it there's very little you can do.  You could `hg strip` it from your local repo, but you'll get it back the next time you pull.  You could edit history with `hg histedit` or merge two changesets with `hg collapse`, but none of that will get rid of the changeset you've **pushed**.

That said, the comment in your screenshot, "I just rolled back my latest push...", has me thinking you might have `hg push` and `hg commit` confused.  They're entirely different and `hg push` can't be rolled back (locally).  A `hg push` sends your local changesets out to the world -- no takebacks.  A `hg commit` creates a new local changeset.

If you've misstated your problem and you've merely `hg commit`ed a changeset you regret you have all the extension-based options I listed above available to you.  If you've really pushed it -- welcome to DVCS usage: once it's out there it's out there, and the best you can do it correct it in a subsequent commit.